# "should I" or "do I need to"? which one is more appropriate?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, expressions

I asked a question on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3310585/678038)

> should I put ... at the end?

in case someone is not familiar to sequence-of-sets, this could be viewed as a punctuation at the end of a sentence (bad analogy).

following expression, which is more appropriate?

expression_1:

should I put ... at the end?

expression_2:

do I need to put ... at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "should" implies some sort of option, where it is more of a suggestion. Whereas "need to" implies necessity (obviously ;-) which means that any other option leaves something out.

In the case of your original question, if you do not write "…" (horizontal ellipsis U+2026) at the end, then you are referencing a (possibly) finite set.